# Replacing text within PPT slides and charts

Tags: r, officer

I've got a PPT template that has around 20 slides. Within the slides, there are shapes, tables and charts that I need to update.

In a lot of cases, it is as simple as: find and replace "xx" in Shape 123 with textABC.

I've been looking at the officer package and trying to figure out how to do this but I've not got it yet. I can print text in a new shape, but can't figure out how to replace part of a string in an existing shape using the same font / format etc.

```
doc <- doc %>%
  on_slide(index = 1) %>%
  ph_with("Hello World", location = ph_location_label(ph_label = "Shape 19"))
```

Comment: Still nothing huh? I'm wondering about this now. Objects will have a label from slide_summary() but I can't seem to use that lable to replace that content using ph_location_label() like you did here.